# Community-wikiing of question

Tags: support, specific-question, community-wiki

It might be a little selfish of me to ask, but why was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1127396/list) (and the answers) community-wikied? Was the (now deleted) user rep gaming or something?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a question for Bill The Lizard, based on the revision history

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1127396/list

Comment: Bill, you have some 'splainin to do!