# Ability to undo the Community Wiki

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, community-wiki

This has always struck me as a strange thing to not have. We have the ability to set things as Community Wiki at the start, and the ability to switch over to Community Wiki after something has been posted. Unfortunately there is no way to move something that is Community Wiki to a traditional post. I haven't even seen a method for this in the moderator tools, and I believe I remember reading something by Jeff saying that it was not possible at this time.

That said, the request is pretty simple. Allow for Community Wiki posts to get reversed back into regular posts. This would include making it an option in the mod tools.

Comment: why is this necessary? can you provide *ANY* reasons it's necessary?

Comment: @Jeff: Some people may unintentionally wikify their question (or have it wikified by others http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6801/community-wikiing-of-question) and desire to reverse the setting.

Comment: Kyle hit the nail on the head. It only makes sense to me and I don't really see how this would be terribly difficult to implement. The only real difficult thing I could imagine is if you try to account for any rep which may be needing to be awarded for votes that came during CW (which I don't think is something you necessarily want to do anyway).

Comment: I am one of those people, I wikied this question when I asked it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645860/what-are-the-programming-religious-wars-of-the-generations-before-our-current-gen) thinking that was best practice and not knowing I do not receive rep points. The comments show people thought it was worthy of a normal question. I want my reps points if possible, but have a haunting feeling it is not. Live and learn -- but hoping there is a way.

Comment: Here is an example when you would want to undo community wiki: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435904/whats-missing-from-this-strategy-of-choosing-which-c-collection-to-use

Comment: Is there any news on the "un-wikification" ?

Comment: @Jeff: how about allowing it for mods only?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8973013/284240) is not my first question accidentally getting community-wiki but the last. It was caused by the OP perpetually changing the requirement and sample data, so i edited my answer once too often. What should i (and others) do in such a case?

Comment: Made a mistake of wiki'ing my answer and just realized there is no undo :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's rare, but sometimes it's fair to have this feature.

In particular, in this question my arm was twisted into community wiki'ng it and since it has received very little attention, I am not motivated to improve it, even though I wrote an open source C# log viewer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784131/are-there-any-c-open-source-log-viewers

In this question, I selected community wiki by mistake before I understood what it meant.

[What's a good threadsafe singleton generic template pattern in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100081/whats-a-good-threadsafe-singleton-generic-template-pattern-in-c)

Comment: I agree and I also suggest to remove the policy to automatically turn an answer after 10 edits into a comm. Wiki. It demotivates people if they aren't rewarded for further improving an answer.

Answer (score 9):

This was fixed up [back in March 16, 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status/83373#83373). Moderators now have the ability to remove the Community Wiki status from any post at their discretion.

Note that now that we no longer automatically convert posts to Community Wiki, the need for moderator intervention should be much lower.

Answer (score 4):

We now no longer allow questions to be marked community wiki by the asker, so the issue is moot.

Comment: Are you sure it is working as intended @Jeff ? Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046142/google-chrome-text-shadow-rendering in revision 12 is shown to be changed to wiki by original author.

Comment: Where are these changes described?

Comment: Can you remove the automatic wikification on questions? The only time I see it come into effect are times like these when too many editors spoil the broth http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311874/why-does-adding-the-where-statement-to-this-sql-make-it-run-so-much-slower

Answer (score 2):

I agree with this as new users still don't read the FAQ even though they are told to. The  same issue with Duplicates, people will see duplicates but still post their question for the potential rep gain. I counted at least 4 possible duplicates on the SU home page today. But I digress.

I support this as long as it is a moderator only function and can be voted for on request of the OP.

Comment: I'm "new" and read the full SO faq stackoverflow.com/faq, but this is not in. Surely, you don't expect anybody to read each and every unsorted post that's marked "FAQ". SOFAQ (which you come across by accident) has about 50 posts now! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sofaq

Comment: @Abel. To be honest it is not such a big request. If you want to be an active part of the community, you need to understand how the system works, and I don't see it being to much to ask of you to read the FAQ's to do that. How else are you going to learn? The system didn't get born overnight and has a strong history.