# Why did my answer become Community Wiki, history says I did that, but I didn't?

Tags: support, community-wiki, specific-answer

This is rather odd. For some reason, my answer became Community Wiki all of a sudden. In the history of the page is says so that I did, but I wouldn't even know how to, so I'm pretty sure I didn't. How can I see who did this and, more importantly, why?

I consider the answer a valid answer and the question a valid question (clear, not subjective etc). The question itself is *not* Community Wiki and in this case, nor should the answer.

How can I (or someone else) change this back? It's all about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658871/pretending-net-strings-are-value-type/1658914#1658914).

Comment: Not knowing how to do something is not proof you didn't do it

Comment: Of course it isn't ;-). This is just such an odd and crazy feature (next to so many excellent ones, I must say), that I just now know that I really should avoid editing my post to get it better, because otherwise.... I might be gaming the system. Good posts are gaming the system? Ouch ouch and ouch, I was about to start loving SO (and probably still will) but this is bad...

Comment: Note for any new readers stumbling across this old Q&A: the automatic conversion of posts to community wiki due to too many edits, as described here, [was removed in 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228947). The only ways in which a question or an answer can now become a community wiki are described in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the last question: It can't be undone.

From the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1658914/list) history, it seems that it was automatically made a wiki after the 10th edit, which is how the system is intended to work. After a certain amount of edits answers and questions are automatically made CW. This is the nature of the trilogy. This is documented in the FAQ [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow/11741#11741)

Comment: What sucks is that there's no warning this is going to happen. It can be quite disheartening to someone who painstakingly reedits a post to get it right, particularly for a newbie.

Comment: Exactly my feeling, Ether. It was a good answer and by simply changing a few typos on the way, it becomes a wiki. Or, if others would change a few typos, I loose my "answer" status and become a "general discussion" or "wiki" status. This is a very sore part of the system. I understand now why people are so terribly reluctant in changing their posts.

Comment: PS, that FAQ link states *"[after] the post has been edited six times by the original owner."*, which is apparently not the case. Why the xx can improving a post mean "gaming the system"?

Comment: @Abel Editing a post will bump the question to the front. When it's there there are people who will check it out and maybe upvote an answer. That's the "gaming the system" part. Trying to milk more upvotes.

Comment: And what'd be wrong in "trying to milk more upvotes" when you do so with quality? Personally, I just intended to improve a post, apparently I was a bit naive (1 month active member, still learning). Now I feel kinda "guilty" for being blamed by the system. 1984 anybody? ;-)

Comment: @Diago: here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6821/ability-to-undo-the-community-wiki you answered that it should be considered possible to revert it. Any news on that or has it been declined?

Comment: There has not been sufficient justification for this and the use cases are rare. So no this is not on the cards as far as I am aware. I agree with the system and see no reason it should change.

Comment: +1 Excellent suggestion Henk! That'd favor quality over reluctance.

Comment: Neither of these are true anymore. Posts no longer become Community Wiki after an arbitrary number of edits, and Moderators can remove the CW flag from a post. Flag the post and use the "in need of moderator intervention" field to explain.